# Vitest: Mocking composable inside of component test

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vitest

I'm having a difficult time **mocking** a composable inside of a component.

Looking to see if a function from the composable was called after a button was clicked.

The composable is quite simple:

```js
export default function useForm() {
  const form = ref({})
  const submit = () => {
    console.log('submit this amazing form')
  }

  return {
    form,
    submit,
  }
}
```

The component is also quite simple:

```js
<template>
  <form>
      <input v-model="form.name" type="text" />
      <button class="submit-button" @click="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import useForm from '@/composable/useForm'

const { form, submit } = useForm()
</script>
```

Now lets test!

Component.spec.js:

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from '@/component/Component.vue'

vi.mock('@/composables/useForm.js', async (importOriginal) => {
  const composable = await importOriginal()
  return {
    ...composable,
    submit: vi.fn(),
  }
})

describe('Component', () => {
  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Component)
  })

  it('should call submit function when button is clicked', async () => {
    await wrapper.find('button.submit-button').trigger('click')

    const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'submit')
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled() // This does not work
  })
})
```

I don't need to call the function, just determine that it was called. The `wrapper` object doesn't seem to have the `submit` available and the mock doesn't seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

I did get something to work with [doMock](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-domock):

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import BaseForm from '../BaseForm.vue'

describe('BaseForm', () => {
  it('submits form', async () => {
    vi.doMock('../../composables/useForm.ts', () => ({
      submit: vi.fn()
    }))

    const wrapper = mount(BaseForm, {})
    const spy = vi.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'submit')

    await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

It seems that `submit` is now part of the Components (I'm going to say the wrong thing here) 'structure' and now can be referenced with `wrapper.vm`.

Answer (score 0):

You're importing from

```js
'@/composable/useForm'
```

but mocking

```js
'@/composables/useForm.js'
//
```

A good rule of thumb for named (non relative) imports is to copy/paste the import path into the mock:

```js
vi.mock('@/composable/useForm', async (original) => ({
  ...(await original()),
  submit: vi.fn()
})
```